# Remove a TFS changeset link from a closed code review work item

Tags: visual-studio-2015

One of our developers accidentally associated a changeset with the wrong code review work item and the code review has since been closed.

Is there anyway to cleanup the paper trail in TFS through Visual Studio 2015 or through command line, so that we can disassociate the changeset and the incorrect code review work item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the incorrect code review work item, then the association will be destroyed automatically.

To delete the single code review work item, simply enter the ID as shown:

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:http://TFSServerName:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /id:63
```

It will cleanup the paper trail in TFS by deleting the useless code review work item, the association with changeset will also be released.

Required permissions:

For Team Services and TFS 2015.2 or later versions, you must have [Permanently delete work items permission set to Allow](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items#move-delete-permissions). For TFS 2015.1 or earlier versions, you must be a member of the Project Administrators group of have Edit project-level information permissions set to Allow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Andy.  Is it possible to unlink the changeset from the code review work item without destroying the work item,  so we can try to link the correct changeset to the code review work item?  Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: @Terry No, you can not link other changeset, the code review work item is created automatically when you submit a **Request Review**, once be closed that means the specific code review task is end, so you can submit a new **Request Review** if you want others to review the code with the correct changeset, but you need to rollback the correct changeset first.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the suggestion Andy!

Comment: @Terry Glad to have been of help! So it will  cleanup the paper trail in TFS by deleting the useless code review work item, the association with changeset will also be released. Feel free to **accept my answer** if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An older question but we ran into this recently using tfs and Visual Studio 2019.  Had gotten a changeset incorrectly linked to a code review request.  Was able to resolve this by searching for the incorrect code review in the tfs web interface by searching for its number in the "Work" menu/tab.  When viewing the code review information there is an option to delete the incorrect link to the changeset.